# Jquery code doesnt work on html output from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this Jquery function to mask my textbox:

```
  jQuery(function($){ //Mask textbox #hour with placeholder
   $("#hour").mask("9:99",{placeholder:"0"});
   $("#hourInTable").mask("9:99",{placeholder:"0"});
});
```

Works perfectly with this html code:

But when I try to do it in the textbox that has the ID hourInTable outputted by Jquery it doesnt mask anything:

```
jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="hourInTable" id="hourInTable" value="00:00">';
```

This above code is called after a button press and the textbox hourInTable is placed somewhere on the page.

Placed this code direct into my html:

```
<input type="text" name="hourInTable" id="hourInTable" value="00:00">
```

And it worked, so its due to the html output in JS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it happens because when jQuery does the masking, the input is not yet present. Give the function a name and call it after you are sure that the innerHTML is placed.

Comment: Perfect worked, stupid me for forgetting this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
 jqTds[2].innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="hourInTable" id="hourInTable" value="00:00">';
 // call after text box is added
 $("#hourInTable").mask("9:99",{placeholder:"0"});
```

because `#hourInTable` is not present on DOM ready so it doesn't apply mask on it

call masking function after your dynamically created input is added

Answer (score 1):

Add the masking code in function. And call it on button click which adds dom `<input type="text" name="hourInTable" id="hourInTable" value="00:00">` in page.